# create a document in mongodb with field that is max + 1

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a document such as

```
{
 increment: 12
}
```

Where the value of increment is the max of all values stored in that collection + 1.

You could separate this into a query and an update, but then you run the risk of a race condition, if two separate calls are are made to the method within an inopportune short period of time.

Is there a way of doing this in a single, atomic call?

Comment: create the document where?Like having 1 collection with that 1 document only?When you you say the max of all values, what do you mean by values?I gave an answer bellow but i dont understand what you need.If you can give an example.

Comment: What do you mean by the "max of all values stored in that collection"? Do all documents in that collection have a field that you want to find the maximum value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) with the option `{"new" :true}`

- updates the document
- returns the updated document (before anyone else can change it)
  without the `new` option it would still update, but return the old document before the update.

*if this is what you are asking for